# What are cost-effective and ways of providing global communication between two devices besides internet and SMS?

Tags: communication, digital-communications, internet

I am currently in the process of building a system which allows vehicles to send information back and forth with an Arduino. The main problem I am facing right now, is that the current implementation assumes that a constant internet connection is present, which in certain areas is clearly not the case.

One solution to this problem is resorting to SMS whenever the internet connection fails, but this still also requires a GSM "network" connection to be present.

Are there any other **cost-effective** means of communication that are widely accessible regardless of the location you are and that do not require either an internet connection or SMS?

TLDR: Are there any cost-effective means of providing **global** communication of two parties that are not within a close proximity of each other, excluding internet or SMS.

Kind regards,

Comment: This is awfully broad. Can you give us some clues about the data bandwidth you require and the amount of latency you can tolerate? Is the data intermittent or continuous? Can you use a store-and-forward service like the LEO satellite network?

Comment: I milliWatt in the HF band will get you 1,000 miles range, but at low data rates. And various regulations apply when you want to use such frequencies. Basically the lower the carrier frequency, the bigger the antenna should be, and the more energy that is gathered up by the receiver, which improves the signal-noise-ratio or  allows higher data rates. Ionospheric behaviors also affect your system.

Answer (score 0):

LORA WAN.
but it is evolving technology.
There are so many companies working on this in setting up towers.